# getting ERROR server.TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 7187667547631101664

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I was able to run a spark(2.0) job earlier, but now I am getting the following error

Looks like when I run in local mode it runs fine, but in client mode its running into this issue. Any ideas?

```
17/10/31 19:02:41 ERROR server.TransportRequestHandler: Error while 
invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 7187667547631101664
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedClusterMessages$RetrieveSparkProps$
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:259)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:308)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:258)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:577)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:562)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:159)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:107)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

creating spark session as

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
```

Was able to run before but now am running into issues

Comment: Did you start Hadoop or whatever NFS you use? I believe this is the error you when it's turned off.